# iOS Invalid transactionId for unfinished trasaction with sandbox test

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I'm testing handling IAP unfinished transactions.

1. Purchase an item with Storekit.
2. Do not finish trasaction.
3. Check pending transactions.

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().transactions
```

4. Check the transactionId.

Then I got an uuid for transactionId.
Like this

```
8A1302D7-40B7-482F-87A9-713B090F1133
```

Correct transactionId format is like '1000000625235554'.

Why I got an incorrect transactionId?